# UNIX shell written in a reasonable language?

Tags: python, unix, shell

Has anyone ever heard of a UNIX shell written in a reasonable language, like Python?

Comment: Do you imply that there is something wrong we c, you philistine?

Comment: Or, to be less flippant, what makes reasonable in the context, and why?

Comment: Just a question: is Python written in a "reasonable" language?

Comment: Related: [Can I use Python as a bash replacement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/209470/95735)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- [Eshell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eshell/index.html) is a Bash-like shell in Emacs Lisp.
- IPython can be [used as a system shell](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/shell.html), though the syntax is a bit weird (supporting all of Python plus basic sh constructs).
- [fish](http://fishshell.com/) has a core written in C, but much of its functionality is implemented in itself. Unlike many rare shells, it can be used as your login shell.
- [Hotwire](https://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/) deserves another mention. Its basic design appears to be "PowerShell in Python," but it also does some clever things with UI. The last release was in 2008.
- [Zoidberg](http://www.pardus.nl/projects/zoidberg/) is written in Perl and uses Perl syntax. A nice-looking project, shame it seems to have stalled.
- [Scsh](http://www.scsh.net/) would be a pain to use as a login shell (an example command from the docs: `(run/strings (find "." -name *.c -print))`), but it looks like a good "Perl in Scheme."

Answer (score 10):

[iPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) (Python) and [Rush](http://rush.heroku.com/) (Ruby) are shells that are designed for more advanced languages. There's also Hotwire, which is sort of a weird integrated shell/terminal emulator.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Rush. I might need to learn Ruby (or re-implement it in Python).

Comment: Rush does look nifty, I'll have to install that and give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

From all appearances, Python IS a shell.  It runs with `#!` and it can run interactively.  Between the `os` and `shutil` packages you have all of the features of standard Unix shells.

Since you can do anything in Python with simple, powerful scripts, you don't really need to spend any time messing with the other shells.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there's emacs, which is arguably a shell written in lisp :)

Seriously though, are you looking for a reimplementation of an existing shell design in a different language such as Python? Or are you looking for a new implementation of a shell language that looks similar to your language of choice?

Answer (score 4):

There is xon now:

http://xon.sh/

http://xon.sh/tutorial.html#running-commands

PyCon video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaje5I22kgE

Answer (score 3):

Tclsh is pretty nice (assuming you like Tcl, of course).

Comment: Well, I'm a philistine about Tcl. You can keep it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [rash](https://github.com/willghatch/racket-rash).  It's a shell language written in Racket.  It has a nice interactive-friendly syntax.  You can embed Rash inside any normal Racket file as well as embedding normal Racket inside Rash.  It's extensible and you can define new pipeline operators.  It's still alpha quality at the moment, but it's pretty cool.  Full disclosure: I wrote it.