# Batch Files. IF statements?

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

i have a batch file that needs to apply the attrib +h command to a file, then output to a txt file and display contents on screen. This should also be done if file has not been provided or can not be found. I have this so far but can not get it to work:

---

```
:TOP
IF EXIST "%1" GOTO COMMAND
) ELSE
(
GOTO ERROR1

:COMMAND
attrib +h %1
SHIFT
GOTO TOP
GOTO END

:ERROR1
IF "%1"=="" GOTO ERROR2
) ELSE
(
GOTO ERROR3

:ERROR2
ECHO.
ECHO No file(s) provided. Please re run the batch file.
GOTO END

:ERROR3
ECHO.
ECHO The file was not found. Please re run the batch file.
GOTO END

:END
```

---

This is my first computer course and any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: **To get you started:** [How the Command Interpreter parses Batch scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/7970912) **Great Resources:** [ss64](http://ss64.com/), [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php), [DosTips](http://www.dostips.com/)

Comment: To make your code more readable, consider renaming the error labels. For instance, instead of ERROR2, say NOFILE. For ERROR3, say NOTFOUND.

Answer (score 13):

There are a few issues with this code. Firstly, batch files require specific syntax with their `IF` / `ELSE` statements.

Something like this

```
IF EXIST "%1" (
    echo "it's here!"
) ELSE (
    echo "it isn't here!"
)
```

works correctly, while something like this

```
IF EXIST "%1" 
(
    echo "it's here!"
) 

ELSE 
(
    echo "it isn't here!"
)
```

does not. The parenthesis delimit the block, so your `IF` command will execute everything in between `(` and `)` if it evaluates to true.

Secondly, you don't actually need any `ELSE` statements. Because you are using `GOTO` commands just before your `ELSE` commands, you will never reach the second `GOTO` command if the first `IF` evaluates to true.

Finally, with the code that you currently show, the `:TOP` tag that you have is unnecessary.

After all of that, you should be left with something that looks like this:

```
@ECHO off
IF EXIST "%1" (
    GOTO COMMAND
)
GOTO ERROR1

:COMMAND
    echo "You entered a file correctly, and it exists!"
    GOTO END

:ERROR1
    IF "%1"=="" (
        GOTO ERROR2
    )
    GOTO ERROR3

:ERROR2
    ECHO.
    ECHO No file(s) provided. Please re run the batch file.
    GOTO END

:ERROR3
    ECHO.
    ECHO The file was not found. Please re run the batch file.
    GOTO END

:END
```

Comment: This makes it a easier to understand, my professor had it formatted differently making it harder to read.

Comment: A tip for the future: don't tell people that this is your homework. You'll probably get more help.

Answer (score 2):

I am not to familiar with Batch, but it looks like your If statement is formatted wrong.

```
IF EXIST "%1" (
    GOTO COMMAND
) ELSE
(
    GOTO ERROR1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just some problems with parenthesis and flow logic

```
@ECHO OFF

    IF "%~1"=="" GOTO ERROR1

:TOP
    IF NOT EXIST "%~1" GOTO ERROR2
    attrib +h "%~1"
    IF "%~2"=="" GOTO END
    SHIFT
    GOTO TOP

:ERROR1
    ECHO.
    ECHO No file(s) provided. Please re run the batch file.
    GOTO END

:ERROR2
    ECHO.
    ECHO The file "%~1" was not found. Please re run the batch file.
    GOTO END

:END
```