# Grep and Python

Tags: python, regex, grep

I need a way of searching a file using grep via a regular expression from the Unix command line. For example when I type in the command line:

```
python pythonfile.py 'RE' 'file-to-be-searched'
```

I need the regular expression `'RE'` to be searched in the file and print out the matching lines.

Here's the code I have:

```
import re
import sys

search_term = sys.argv[1]
f = sys.argv[2]

for line in open(f, 'r'):
    if re.search(search_term, line):
        print line,
        if line == None:
            print 'no matches found'
```

But when I enter a word which isn't present, `no matches found` doesn't print

Comment: If you really want for python-style regular expressions in grep, the --perl-regex option to grep is really close.  It gives you perl-style regular expression support.  (Also, my favorite underused option to grep is --color=always )

Answer (score 97):

The natural question is why not just use grep?! But assuming you can't...

```
import re
import sys

file = open(sys.argv[2], "r")

for line in file:
     if re.search(sys.argv[1], line):
         print line,
```

Things to note:

- `search` instead of `match` to find anywhere in string
- comma (`,`) after `print` removes carriage return (line will have one)
- `argv` includes python file name, so variables need to start at 1

This doesn't handle multiple arguments (like grep does) or expand wildcards (like the Unix shell would). If you wanted this functionality you could get it using the following:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import sys
import glob

regexp = re.compile(sys.argv[1])
for arg in sys.argv[2:]:
    for fn in glob.iglob(arg):
        with open(fn) as file:
            for line in file:
                if re.search(regexp, line):
                    print(line, end='')
```

Comment: you should compile your regex before using the loops.

Comment: This has two down votes and I have no idea why. Anyone who downvoted want to leave a comment? I know you could add regex compilation etc, but I thought that would detract from the clarity of the answer. I don't think there is anything incorrect, and I've run the code, unlike some of the other answers

Comment: This answer was perfect for me thanks. Just another quick question how would i print if no matches were found?

Comment: add a counter, and increase it if a match happens. At the end check it in an if and print if no answers found

Comment: ok i put a line counter in which counts the number of lines. But when i execur=te the program nothing is printed. i.e. it wont print 'no matches found'

Comment: can you add this problem as another stack overflow question, and show your source code as it looks at the moment? put a reference to this question, and give me a comment with the new question number

Comment: "you should compile your regex before using the loops.", No, Python will compile and cache it on its own, it's a common myth, it's a nice thing to do for readability reasons, htough.

Comment: For Python 3 I found that `print(line,)` wouldn't remove the extra line breaks. However for all the list comprehension junkies out there, this works nicely and removes line breaks `print(''.join([line for line in open(sys.argv[2], 'r') if re.search(sys.argv[1], line)]))`

Comment: The reasonable answer to the natural question is "Because the code is part of a much larger Python script, and who wants to call out to grep in such a case?" In short, I'm glad this question is here because I'm replacing a bash script with a Python script that is hopefully easier on the system.

Comment: The answer to the question for me is "we want to grep in production logs on a Windows machine where they don't have proper grep, only a useless baregrep tool but all our clients will have Python installed as our system uses it".

Comment: re.findall to mimic grep better as re.search only returns the first match

Comment: @CashCow `grep` is such a vital tool for specific purposes and has been optimised fiendishly over the decades. Cygwin would be the way to go on a crappy old Windoze box. But your client or whoever would have to have installed it, haha. Of course, `grep` has one fatal flaw (per my understanding): it is single-thread ... it will be superseded eventually.

Answer (score 13):

Concise and memory efficient:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# file: grep.py
import re, sys, collections

collections.deque(map(sys.stdout.write,(l for l in sys.stdin if re.search(sys.argv[1],l))),maxlen=0)
```

It works like egrep (without too much error handling), e.g.:

```
cat input-file | grep.py "RE"
```

And here is the one-liner:

```
cat input-file | python -c "import re,sys,collections;collections.deque(map(sys.stdout.write,(l for l in sys.stdin if re.search(sys.argv[1],l))),maxlen=0)" "RE"
```

Note that the `collections.deque` function is required in Python3 because map has become a lazy function.

Comment: lowercase "L" as a variable name: Please never do that again.
https://pep8.org/#names-to-avoid

Answer (score 9):

Adapted from a [grep in python](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ginsbura/pygrep.htm).

Accepts a list of filenames via `[2:]`, does no exception handling:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re, sys, os

for f in filter(os.path.isfile, sys.argv[2:]):
    for line in open(f).readlines():
        if re.match(sys.argv[1], line):
            print line
```

`sys.argv[1]` resp `sys.argv[2:]` works, if you run it as an standalone executable, meaning

`chmod +x`

first

Comment: what's the difference between `re.match`  and   `re.search` ?

Comment: @OscarRyz see [Nick Fortescue's top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1921932/327074): "`search` instead of `match` to find anywhere in string"

Answer (score 5):

1. use `sys.argv` to get the command-line parameters
2. use `open()`, `read()` to manipulate file
3. use the [Python re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to match lines

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in [pyp](http://pyvideo.org/video/686/the-pyed-piper-a-modern-python-alternative-to-aw). Citing my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12915952/95735):

> "The Pyed Piper", or pyp, is a linux command line text manipulation
>   tool similar to awk or sed, but which uses standard python string and
>   list methods as well as custom functions evolved to generate fast
>   results in an intense production environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use python-textops3 :

```
from textops import *

print('\n'.join(cat(f) | grep(search_term)))
```

with python-textops3 you can use unix-like commands with pipes

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is that the variable line always has a value. The test for "no matches found" is whether there is a match so the code "if line == None:" should be replaced with "else:"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your question was clear to me but to fix your code just change your if expression like the following:

```
import re
import sys

search_term = sys.argv[1]
f = sys.argv[2]
r = None
n = 0
with open(f, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        n=n+1
        r = re.search(search_term, line)
        if r:
            print(f"{line} found at line {n}")
if not r:
    print('no matches found')
```

PS: I tested it on Python 3.8.10

if you want to use grep you could

```
grep -E '(.*)word(.*)' file.txt || echo "pattern not found"
```