# Python replacement of Rubys grep?

Tags: python, ruby

```
abc=123
dabc=123
  abc=456
  dabc=789
    aabd=123
```

From the above file I need to find lines beginning with abc= (whitespaces doesn't matter)

in ruby I would put this in an array and do

```
matches = input.grep(/^\s*abc=.*/).map(&:strip)
```

I'm a totally noob in Python, even said I'm a fresh Python developer is too much.

Maybe there is a better "Python way" of doing this without even grepping ?

The Python version I have available on the platform where I need to solve the problem is 2.6

There is no way of use Ruby at that time

Comment: Is this what you want?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921894/grep-and-python

Comment: thanks!, will definately help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
    matches = [line.rstrip() for line in myfile if line.lstrip().startswith("abc=")]
```

Comment: +1 startswith for clarity.  I'd use `with open("myfile.txt") as myfile`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the outcome: https://github.com/astropanic/Compline As I said, I'm not a python pro, so please bear with me ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Python you would typically use a list comprehension whose `if` clause does what you'd accomplish with Ruby's `grep`:

```
import sys, re
matches = [line.strip() for line in sys.stdin
           if re.match(r'^\s*abc=.*', line)]
```