# most efficient way to search for a word in multiple files

Tags: python, string, performance, file, search

For my master thesis i downloaded a ton of finance related files. my objective is to find a specific set of words ("chapter 11") to flag all companies that have gone through the debt restructuring process.
The problem is that i have more than 1.2 milion little files that makes the search really inefficient. For now i wrote very basic code and i reached a velocity of 1000 documents every 40-50 seconds. i was wondering if there are some specific libraries or methods (or even programming languages) to search even faster. this is the function i'm using so far

```
def get_items(m):
    word = "chapter 11"
    f = open(m, encoding='utf8')
    document = f.read()
    f.close()
    return (word in document.lower())
# apply the function to the list of names:
l_v1 = list(map(get_items,filenames))
```

the size of the files varies between 5 and 4000 KB

Comment: you can employ a fulltext search engine like Elasticsearch.

Comment: Do you need to do this in Python? In Windows you could use the findstr or Select-String commands, or grep in Linux.

Comment: python or any other programming language would be better. but i'm going to try the grep solution in Linux too

Comment: You might want to look at the various suggestions on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921894/grep-and-python

Comment: Maybe my suggest not relate to python. I think you can try some software, like 'DocFetcher' or others.

Comment: `in` is potentially slow; first building a RegEx from `word` should guarantee linear search. Your bottleneck is going to be reading the files however.

Comment: true, in fact I was looking for more efficient methods to open files too

Comment: You have 1.2 million filenames in a Python list. Really? How are you building that list? My reason for asking is because it might be appropriate to incorporate the file processing (search) into acquisition of the files of interest

Comment: directory = 'TXT FILES 0-328635'
filenames = []
for filename in glob(directory + '/*'): 
  filenames.append(filename)

Comment: basically i have a folder with all the files and i'm stuffing the list with their names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly different approach where we use multithreading to build a list of filenames that contain the string 'chapter 11'

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

filenames = [] # list of filenames
results = [] # list of filenames containing 'chapter 11'
word = 'chapter 11' # lowercase

def process(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            if word in infile.read().lower():
                results.append(filename)
    except Exception:
        pass

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process, filenames)

print(results)
```

EDIT:

OP has said that all files to be processed are in a single directory/folder. In that case, rather than building a list of filenames one could do this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from os.path import join
from os import listdir
import re

results = [] # list of filenames containing 'chapter 11'
cp = re.compile('chapter 11', re.IGNORECASE)
DIR = '' # directory containing files to be processed

def process(filename):
    try:
        with open(join(DIR, filename), encoding='utf-8') as infile:
            if cp.search(infile.read()):
                results.append(filename)
    except Exception:
        pass

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process, listdir(DIR))

print(results)
```

This change also incorporates the idea of using a regular expression for searching for the pattern which may or may not be more efficient that using *in*

Comment: your code dropped the time to 5 seconds for 1000 files. i think i love you lol

Comment: i just tried it on some random samples. It is way more efficient than mine. From my calculations it should take from 3 to 4 hours to complete the first 300.000 documents. finger crossed. i'll make an update :D

Comment: It took just 1 hour and half to complete. This is great!

Answer (score 5):

Try the Unix tool, `grep`.

If the files are few, you can do:

```
grep -i "chapter 11" file1 file2 ...
```

Or,

```
grep -i "chapter 11" file*.txt
```

If there are many files, you can combine `grep` with `find`:

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -i "chapter 11"
```

Another powerful tool is `ack` (written in Perl) -- see https://beyondgrep.com/.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use **threading** to split the filenames list into two or smaller lists and search simultaneously.

[threading explanation](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)

[threading library docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

here's an example:

```
import threading

def get_items(m):
    word = "chapter 11"
    f = open(m, encoding='utf8')
    document = f.read()
    f.close()
    return (word in document.lower())
# apply the function to the list of names:
l_v1 = list(map(get_items,filenames))

x = threading.Thread(target=get_items, args=(l_v1[:len(l_v1) // 2],))
y = threading.Thread(target=get_items, args=(l_v1[len(l_v1) // 2:],))

x.start()
y.start()
```

Comment: thank you so much, i'm trying it now