# Search a word by lastname from a text file and print the output which has similar lastname in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Text file data :
sponsors.txt file that has stored data with their names and donations

```
John Smith,230.5
Sally Jones,380
Mary Smith,104.55
David McDougal,165.7
Sally Matthews,184.5
Peter Evans,300.25
```

Expected Output :

```
Please enter a search string: Smith
Search returned 2 results:
John Smith,230.5
Mary Smith,104.55
```

MyCode:

```
def read_sponsor_data(file_path, word):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
        name_count = content.count(list_sponsor)
        if word in content:
            print('Search returned', name_count, 'results:')
        else:
            print('Search returned no results.')
        for i in range(0, name_count):
            print(content)
    file.close()


if search_sponsor == 1:
    list_sponsor = input("Please enter a search string: ")
    read_sponsor_data("sponsors.txt", list_sponsor)
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

My Output :

```
Please enter a search string: Smith
Search returned 2 results:
John Smith,230.5
Sally Jones,380
Mary Smith,104.55
David McDougal,165.7
Sally Matthews,184.5
Peter Evans,300.25
John Smith,230.5
Sally Jones,380
Mary Smith,104.55
David McDougal,165.7
Sally Matthews,184.5
Peter Evans,300.25
```

Comment: `for i in range(0, name_count):
            print(content)` that prints the entire file `name_count` files right? You want to perform a line-by-line search to get the rest of the data you're looking for

Comment: check this (regex but same principle): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921894/grep-and-python

Comment: Furthermore, it should be `name_count = content.count(word)`

Answer (score 1):

`file.read()` reads the whole file as a string. This string has the inputed name 2 times. Then you print this whole string 2 times. You probably need `file.readlines()` or iterate over `file` (i.e. over lines):

```
def read_sponsor_data(file_path, word):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        matched_lines = [l for l in file if word in l]

    if matched_lines:
        print('Search returned', len(matched_lines), 'results:')
        for l in matched_lines:
            print(l)
    else:
        print('Search returned no results.')
```

Comment: I prefer `name_count > 0`. I think it's more explicit

Comment: fair enough but more pythonic: check if list is not empty with `if matched_lines:`, compute length later if needed. Your call anyway

Comment: i want to iterate over file so i can get my expected output.

Comment: all i want is when i enter a substring like smith it iterate the file and show the two names and their values as per substring. Any helpful Tips???

Comment: Doesn't the code in my answer produce the result you mention in your question?