# How to create a user in linux using python

Tags: python, linux, shell

How do I create a user in Linux using Python? I mean, I know about the subprocess module and thought about calling 'adduser' and passing all the parameters at once, but the 'adduser' command asks some questions like password, full name, phone and stuff. How would I answer this questions using subprocess?
   I've seen  module called pexpect in this question: [Can I use Python as a Bash replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209470/can-i-use-python-as-a-bash-replacement). Is there any other standard module?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `useradd`, it doesn't ask any questions but accepts many command line options.

Comment: how about using `libuser` python binding to perform this operation?

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu, you could use the [python-libuser](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-libuser) package

Comment: Is this a ubuntu-only package? If I need to run it on other distros, will I have to manually install this package?

Comment: You are probably better off with `useradd` for cross-distribution compatibility, but note that even `useradd` is not guaranteed to be available on all distros. Puppy Linux I believe does not come with useradd by default, for example.

Comment: `python-libuser` link is dead => https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/libuser

Answer (score 5):

```
import os
import crypt

password ="p@ssw0rd" 
encPass = crypt.crypt(password,"22")
os.system("useradd -p "+encPass+" johnsmith")
```

Comment: what's the number 22 for? Is this still the proper way to encrypt in 2017?

Comment: 22 is a salt. You can use random values. If you want to extra security you can use sha-256 or sha-512

Comment: It **has** to be "22". The command `useradd` expects a specific hash.

Comment: Does it require a `sudo` permission? @Jonathan Rioux

Answer (score 3):

You could just use the built-in binaries so just call useradd or something through the subprocess module, However I don't know if there's any other modules that hook into Linux to provide such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

```
def createUser(name,username,password):
    encPass = crypt.crypt(password,"22")   
    return  os.system("useradd -p "+encPass+ " -s "+ "/bin/bash "+ "-d "+ "/home/" + username+ " -m "+ " -c \""+ name+"\" " + username)
```

Comment: What's the number 22 for? Also, would subprocess be better than os.system?

Comment: @answerSeeker it is salt. salt is a 2-character string
which will be used to select one of 4096 variations of DES. (from pydoc)

Comment: sorry for the necrobump, but crypt can generate a salt for you, no need to specify.

    salt = crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)
    salthash = crypt.crypt(password, salt)

see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypt.html#crypt.mksalt) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution where `shell` is false.

```py
#!/bin/env/python

import subprocess
import traceback
import sys


def user_add(username, user_dir=None):
    if user_dir:
        cmd = ["sudo", "useradd", "-d", user_dir, "-m", username]
    else:
        cmd = ["sudo", "useradd", username]

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = p.communicate()
    output = output.strip().decode("utf-8")
    error = error.decode("utf-8")
    if p.returncode != 0:
        print(f"E: {error}")
        raise
    return output


try:
    username = "user"
    output = user_add(username)
    print(F"Success. {username} is added")
except:
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)
```