# How to create an user in linux using python libuser

Tags: python

I am using today the command adduser of linux with OS library. But would like to use the python libuser for administrative commands as add a new user.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190955/how-to-create-a-user-in-linux-using-python

Comment: Diego Herranz, it don't a duplcate. I would like how to create an user in linux using the libuser. This ask show only how to create an user in linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the creation of the `jimbo` user in https://pagure.io/libuser/blob/master/f/python/test-script

Comment: On your script I am having following error: `SystemError: could not open configuration file `/etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory`

Comment: Not my script, I pointed to an existing script which is part of the libuser codebase.  Looks like the library code requires the config file to exist.  So, perhaps create it?

Comment: Also should I run the script with `sudo`?