# Python fabric How to send password and yes/no for user prompt

Tags: python, shell, hadoop, fabric

I have created a fabfile with multiple hosts.

I am automating my experiment. When i run the command "sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser" it will ask for the following.

1. New unix password
2. confirm Password.
3. Full Name
4. Room,Ph,etc
5. is this information Correct? Y/N

I would like to pass all this information as part of script without prompting user. How can i do this ?

Thanks

Navaz

Comment: I think this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190955/how-to-create-a-user-in-linux-using-python) or anyway, it'll help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't you just use pipes?

For example, for an automated auto accept, just use yes, that just outputs a neverending stream of y.

```
yes | rm *.txt
```

in your case:

```
local('echo 'your_super_password\n' | sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `fexpect`, an extension of fabric that enables you to respond to prompts:

```
from ilogue.fexpect import expect, expecting, run 

prompts = []
prompts += expect('What is your full name?','John Doe')
prompts += expect('is this information Correct? Y/N','Y')

with expecting(prompts):
    sudo('adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser')
```