# Give response yes/no in python when a command is executed os.system() in python linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, os.system

Consider a command like

```
yum install boto
```

When I execute in terminal, to proceed is asks me for yes/no

Can I respond to it in python like

```
os.system("yum install boto")
```

Next `"Yes"`  is to be passed to terminal through the same python code so that it installs. Well, I dont think this works. If it is written after tha above statement

```
os.system("yes")
```

Please tell me if this is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running an interactive command from within python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457931/running-an-interactive-command-from-within-python)

Comment: There's also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567371/wrapping-an-interactive-command-line-application-in-a-python-script?lq=1 (and probably a few more...) I searched for: [python subprocess interactive](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python%20subprocess%20interactive)

Comment: There are ways to do this, but the usual solution is to use a command-line option that prevents the program from asking questions.

Comment: [how about just tell yum to accept everything](http://serverfault.com/questions/442088/how-do-you-answer-yes-for-yum-install-automatically)

Comment: I dont run yum actually, I run `sudo scp -i` for transferring files between two ec2 instances

Comment: I think it's the passing of yes and no that is at issue here - so this might be a more appropriate duplicate (it suggests using a pipe) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615113/python-fabric-how-to-send-password-and-yes-no-for-user-prompt.  However, this also has a good answer below that is not duplicated on that question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use subprocess.Popen and write to stdin, you need the `-S` flag for sudo then just the rest of the commands.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import getpass

pwd = getpass.getpass()
proc = Popen(['sudo', '-S', rest of commands ],stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
proc.stdin.write("{}\n".format(pwd))
out,err = proc.communicate(input="{}\n".format("yes"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a pipe and do

```
yes | os.system("yum install boto")
```

it will repeat yes until the command is done