# Use of adduser --home linux by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I need to create a user with home directory in python. Currently, i am doing this:

`adduser --home /test testing`

But, this requires some inputs as well. How do i execute such command and give the input in python?

Input is asking password, room number, and etc.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a user in linux using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190955/how-to-create-a-user-in-linux-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useradd` instead of `adduser` you can specify the password and [more](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) via in CLI (I guess you are or should use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html))

Please note in future as per SO [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first search for similar questions before asking a new question. For example the answer to your question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3190970/4451944)

Comment: thank you very much, now i can add params :)