# Pass complex object to a python script in command line

Tags: python, command-line, arguments

I am beginner in Python programing, I want to pass a complex object (Python dictionary or class object) as an argument to a python script using command line (cmd). I see that **sys.argv** gets only string parameters.

Here is an example of what I want:

```
class point(object):
     def __init__(self,x,y):
         self.__x=x
         self.__y=y
p=point(4,8)
import os
os.system('""xxxxxx.exe" "-s" "../create_scenario.py" "'+ p +'""')
```

The xxxxxx.exe  is a program which accept to run a python script with the -s option. Thanks for all!!!

Comment: Sorry, we don't do *urgent* here. For time-critical answers, please hire a consultant.

Comment: `os.system` is really bad.

Comment: Your only option is to save it to a file. On a side note: using `__x` is for name mangling which I'm pretty sure you don't need in the `point` class. You might have wanted a private variable `_x` if you have getter and setter functions/property but otherwise just leave it as `self.x`

Comment: segfolt >>  What to use so if os.system is really bad ?

Comment: See this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479728/is-it-good-style-to-call-bash-commands-within-a-python-script-using-os-systemb

Answer (score 1):

You could try serialize\deserialize to\from a string using a pickle module.
Look for [dumps](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) and [loads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
my_dict = eval(sys.argv[1])
print(my_dict)
```

Comand prompt:

```
$ my_script.py {1:2}
$ {1: 2}
```

But what you want to do is not recommended ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)). You should avoid this and store your data in a file instead (using [JSON](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html) for example).

Comment: Thank you. But how to use exec ?

Comment: I did slight changes to my post.

Comment: There are better alternatives than `eval`. Using JSON for example.