# Writing a Shell in Python?

Tags: python, shell

Why is this such a bad idea? (According to many people)

Comment: Python **is** a shell.  What are you asking?  What does "according to many people" mean?  Can you provide a link or a reference?

Comment: Probably only according to some diehard freaks who must write *everything* in C ...

Comment: it does not have to be c.. c++ is fine too ;)

Comment: I'm saying writing a more useable shell, such as a replacement  for bash that works on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X as well as including a package manager that runs on all of those with packages for them (assuming it goes somewhere and people make software for it other than myself)

Comment: By many people, I meant people of 4chan's /g/ http://boards.4chan.org/g/res/12517021#12517373
and people I've spoken with over instant messenger

Comment: Well, they already have their own shells. Windows users don't generally use `cmd`, but it's there.

Comment: Python already is "a more useable shell, such as a replacement for bash".  It already does this.  What are you asking?

Comment: I'm saying one that works on all of them and is more universal

Comment: Python's Shell is extremely difficult compared to Bash

Comment: @Indebi: Don't listen to /g/, there are no places with more trolls, even on 4chan. Although, the general argument would probably be that python introduces large unnecessary overhead, and that python already is a shell.

Comment: But does the people of StackOverFlow think this is a good idea

Comment: I don't think its a good idea. But I don't think it's a bad one at all. This is way too subjective IMHO

Comment: @Indebi: It doesn't matter what we think.  It already exists.  You can use Python instead of bash.  Right now.  No additional development or work.  Just use it.  We do it all the time to write portable scripts.

Comment: It would only make sense if it is a solution to an actual problem. State the problem & it's consequences, then state how your Python Shell will solve those problems, and then we can discuss whether that solution is viable / worth the effort.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a bad idea. Lots of people use IPython which is a shell written in Python :)

In fact you may want to base your effort around IPython. scipy does this, for example

Comment: +1: We use Python instead of Bash or CMD.EXE.  It's portable.

Comment: +1 for IPython. 
Using IPython with the sh profile (`ipython -p sh`) works really well as a replacement for bash etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought it was quite a cool idea. Last time I got the urge to give it a go I was thinking about a maple-style worksheet interface for Python. Sadly I can't find the very cool Python+GTK+Cairo code for an interactive shell that is out there somewhere, but searching now I did come across a couple of things that might interest you.

[Reinteract](http://people.gnome.org/~otaylor/reinteract-demo.html) is very close to what I had in mind.

[PyShell](http://pyshell.sourceforge.net/) is closer to a traditional shell, the source is available and it says on the website that he's seeking help.

Edit: This older question on [unix shell written in a reasonable language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171267/unix-shell-written-in-a-reasonable-language) was a related link and has lots more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Another shell written in Python is [hotwire](http://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/) - it has some interesting ideas and a mix of commandline and gui interface.  It is written in Python but can let you freely intermix code in sh, python, perl and ruby, plus its own language 'HotWirePipe'.

Unfortunately the main site for it seems to have died, but it is [archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20080704152246/http://hotwire-shell.org/) in the wayback machine.